# Stop backbone validation of collection if one model fails validation

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to stop backbone validation of colelction if one model fails validation? Currently, the code does this (taken from Backbone.js 1.1.0):

```
for (i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++) {
    attrs = models[i];
    if (attrs instanceof Model) {
        id = model = attrs;
    } else {
        id = attrs[targetModel.prototype.idAttribute];
    }

    // If a duplicate is found, prevent it from being added and
    // optionally merge it into the existing model.
    if (existing = this.get(id)) {
        if (remove) modelMap[existing.cid] = true;
        if (merge) {
            attrs = attrs === model ? model.attributes : attrs;
            if (options.parse) attrs = existing.parse(attrs, options);
            existing.set(attrs, options);
            if (sortable && !sort && existing.hasChanged(sortAttr)) sort = true;
        }
        models[i] = existing;

        // If this is a new, valid model, push it to the `toAdd` list.
    } else if (add) {
        model = models[i] = this._prepareModel(attrs, options);
        if (!model) continue;
        toAdd.push(model);

        // Listen to added models' events, and index models for lookup by
        // `id` and by `cid`.
        model.on('all', this._onModelEvent, this);
        this._byId[model.cid] = model;
        if (model.id != null) this._byId[model.id] = model;
    }
    if (order) order.push(existing || model);
}
```

So if _prepareModel returns false, which it will if a model is invalid, it will skip to next model and try to validate and add that.

I want to stop if one of the models fails validation? The app I'm working on is a tablet app and thousands of models are returned from the server (represented of course as JSON) so if the first model fails validation, I do not want all the others to be validated too, as the entire collection will be disguarded.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: You could iterate on the collection and call `model.validate()` on each model. Or am I missing something?

Comment: well I would like to do it from within fetch. At the moment if you call fetch() and pass in {validate:true}, each model is validated as you set it in the collection. I want to quit if any model fails validation

Comment: hmm. IMO it makes no sense the models returned from the server are invalid. validation is typically for user input, and data stored on the server should always be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would override the `fetch` method on your collection. Like this:

```
youCollection.fetch = function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
  var success = options.success;
  var collection = this;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    if (success) {
      if (success(collection, resp, options))
        collection[method](resp, options);
    } else
        collection[method](resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
}
```

Here's what's happening. Focus on the line that starts with `options.success =`. When your server comes back with your requested models, a trigger invokes the function defined by `options.success` passing your models in as a parameter. In the **original code**, `options.success` looks like this:

```
 options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    collection[method](resp, options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
```

What matters here that `collection[method](resp, options);` invokes set on the `collection` that called the fetch. And only then you have the option to invoke your own callback. Once `collection.set` is called, the validation loop on your models begins and there's nothing we could do.

We want to change that up. We want to first call our own success function. This function will run a `for loop` checking if each `model.isValid()`, and will return false as soon as one fails. If one does fail we never reach `collection[method](resp, options);` and set never happens.

To get a `success` function into your `fetch` call simply drop a reference to it in the options passed into `fetch`

```
yourCollection.fetch({ success: checkValidate });
```

I would additionally point you to [Backbone.validate](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) so that you can read about the 'invoke' trigger that gets fired when a model is invalid. That way you can handle another fetch or whatever.